# Open inside link in parent window with Fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I use Fancybox to open inline content in a box. In the content there are some links that has to be opened in the main window of the browser. The problem is that Fancybox tries to open these links in the Fancybox window. I tried several things like closing the Fancybox first or using targer="_parent" but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you're interested, I came up with another solution. Apply the following to content to be displayed within the box:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    window.parent.location = link;
});
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the other solution but I currently don't need it but I'll keep it in mind for next projects

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution in a simple way. Just add this to the onclick-parameter of the a-tag: windows.location.href='url';